# How to update existing Font in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, textbox

In Windows Forms, I have a textbox which I want user to set its font style.

Something like:

```
   Font font = new Font(textBox1.Font,FontStyle.Regular);
   if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        font= new Font(font,FontStyle.Bold);
   if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
        font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Italic);
   if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
        font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Underline);
   textBox1.Font = font;
```

The thing is if two of checkboxes are selected I would have to do like:

```
font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Italic|FontStyle.Italic);
```

Then check all possible combinations.
Is there a way to define a font then add properties to its style? instead of checking all possible if combinations.

something like:

```
Font font= new Font();
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        font.Bold=true;
   if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
        font.Italic=true;
   if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
        font.Underline=true;
```

Comment: Can't you just make events for the check boxes rather than if statements, then you should only need to adapt one property at a time?

Comment: you are right, but the question still stands, how to adapt the property?

Comment: Once I set the Font I can not find a way to update its style again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fonts are immutable, so you can't change a font once it's created.
What you can do is have a variable to hold the font style, and do something like this:

```
var fontStyle = FontStyle.Regular;

if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {fontStyle |= FontStyle.Bold;}
if (checkBox2.Checked)
    {fontStyle |= FontStyle.Italic;}
if (checkBox3.Checked)
    {fontStyle |= FontStyle.Underline;}

textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, fontStyle);
```